# AngularJS Custom Search Filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I want to use the default `filter` filter to browse through some data, but need added functionality to narrow down the search results, ie. additional checkboxes. Can I extend the default filter, or do I have to write a new one from scratch, handling everything, including DOM manipulation to show / hide results?

Comment: Metzger check out my answer.........

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan, this morning you created numerous tags for AngularJS that *already existed* under different spellings.  Please always search thoroughly first!

Comment: @charles ive created since...I couldnt find any those easiliy....I sincerely apologise. ..if it is wrong....